# Call child component methods step by step from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

I have a `ParentComponent` with multiple `ChildComponent`s like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
    <child-component :bus="bus" />
    <child-component :bus="bus" />
    <child-component :bus="bus" />
   .
   .
   .
    <child-component :bus="bus" />
    </div>
</template>
```

I am using `bus` to fire a test method on all children and there is an AJAX call in all those test methods.

But when I emit the event to the bus with...

```js
this.bus.$emit('test')
```

...then all test methods get called at the same time.

I want to make it step by step; for example it should wait for the AJAX call in the first child-component to finish and then try to call the test method in next child-component.

I did try with `_.debounce` and `_.throttle` but it didn't work.

Comment: Ajax is inheriently asynchronous.  Given that these components are going to be working independently of each other, its not entirely straightforward how you are going to make them be self aware of each other.  Or in the least, make their ajax calls aware of each other.

Comment: I guess the question I have to ask is, are the ajax calls for each component different for each component?  And if not, is it really necessary that each component makes it's own duplicate ajax call?  Would it perhaps make more sense for the parent to make one ajax call, and then give all the children the results?

Comment: @Taplar they have same ajax call in their method - but with different post params ... and there is submit button in each of them that works separately - but the thing im asking is for SUBMITALL button which is in parent component for all of them . but the problem is if they are 30 childs ... calling 30 ajax requests at a single time is bad and I want to make a single ajax call at once for each.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is there a reason you pass a bus to each component instead of using a global bus? 2) Is there a reason you use a bus instead of Vuex?